# Interrupted apt but no error

Tags: apt

I was testing an example snap when I interrupted `Ctrl+c` when it had downloaded and was reading the packages. The output showed some python stuff. After that I installed the packages normally. Apt is working fine, checked the logs and they look good. I also ran `dpkg --configure -a` and saw no output. So am I good? I always have this feeling that something can go wrong and I wouldn't know about it.

Comment: you should be fine if you didn't see any errors when you ran `dpkg --configure -a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No unusual output in the terminal generally indicates that there isn't any package management problem.

In order to dig deeper install sosreport from the default Ubuntu repositories. If sosreport finds an error, it will save the error report in a separate .txt file.

```
sudo apt install sosreport
```

Then run sosreport.

```
sosreport
```

The output will be a .tar.xz archive located in the `/tmp` folder. Copy the archive to your home folder and extract the contents to read the results of the `sosreport` command. The .tar.xz archive may contain .txt files whose names are diagnostic commands that were run by the sosreport program and the contents of these files are the results of running the diagnostic commands.